# Acumatica mobile app allocations not working

Tags: mobile, customization, acumatica

I am trying to write the Shipments widget for the Acumatica mobile app so that it can be used more like the web browser.
Specifically I want to be able to add serial numbers and bin locations to the line inventory items.
The problem I am having is if the line item has quantity 2 or more, I cannot get the Allocations screen to popup so that you can select and enter multiple SN's for that shipping line item.  The error I most often receive is "Server error : 404".  Which obviously means it is not finding/generating the web page for mobile app display.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to what I am doing wrong?

Here is the code:

```
  add container "ShipmentSummary" {
    formActionsToExpand = 5
    add layout "ShipmentHeader" {
      displayName = "ShipmentHeader"
      layout = "HeaderSimple"
      add layout "ShipmentHeaderNbrRow" {
        displayName = "ShipmentHeaderNbrRow"
        layout = "Inline"
        add field "ShipmentNbr"
        add field "Status"
      }
      add layout "ShipmentQtyRow" {
        displayName = "ShipmentQtyRow"
        layout = "Inline"
        add field "Operation"
        add field "ShippedQuantity"
      }
      add layout "ShipmentCustomerRow" {
        displayName = "ShipmentCustomerRow"
        layout = "Inline"
        add field "Customer"
      }
      add layout "ShipmentWarehouseID" {
        displayName = "ShipmentWarehouseID"
        layout = "Inline"
        add field "WarehouseID"
      }
      add layout "ShipmentLocation" {
        displayName = "ShipmentLocation"
        layout = "Inline"
        add field "Location"
      }
    }

    add field "ShipmentDate" {
      selectorDisplayFormat = Key
      pickerType = Detached
    }
    add field "Workgroup" {
      pickerType = Detached
    }
    add field "Owner" {
      pickerType = Detached
    }
    add field "Description"

    add group "OrderInfoGroup" {
      displayName = "Orders"
      collapsable = True
      collapsed = True
      add layout "OrdersLineInfo" {
        displayName = "OrdersLineInfo"
        layout = "Inline"
        add field "Orders#OrderType"
        add field "Orders#OrderNbr"
      }
      add layout "LineInvoiceInfo" {
        displayName = "LineInvoiceInfo"
        layout = "Inline"
        add field "Orders#InvoiceType"
        add field "Orders#InvoiceNbr"
      }
      add field "Orders#NoteText" {
        displayName = "Order Notes"
        textType = PlainMultiLine
      }    
    }
    
    add layout "DetailsTab" {
      displayName = "Details"
      layout = "DataTab"
      add containerLink "DocumentDetails"
    }  
    add recordAction "Save" {
      behavior = Save
    }
    add recordAction "Cancel" {
      behavior = Cancel
    }
    add containerAction "Insert" {
      icon = "system://Plus"
      behavior = Create
      redirect = True
    }
    add recordAction "PutOnHoldAction" {
      behavior = Record
    }
    add recordAction "ReleaseFromHoldAction" {
      behavior = Record
    }
    add recordAction "ConfirmShipmentActionAction" {
      behavior = Record
    }      
    attachments {
    }
  }
    
  add container "DocumentDetails" {
    fieldsToShow = 2
    listActionsToExpand = 1
    formActionsToExpand = 2
    containerActionsToExpand = 1
    add group "LineInventoryIdGroup" {
      displayName = "LineInventoryIdGroup"
      collapsed = True
      template = ExpansionPanel
        add field "InventoryID" {
          listPriority = 100
          selectorDisplayFormat = Key
          pickerType = Searchable
        }
        add field "Description" {
          listPriority = 90
        }
    }
    add field "Location"
    add field "LotSerialNbr"
    add layout "LineQuantityRow" {
      displayName = "LineQuantityRow"
      layout = "Inline"
      add field "ShippedQty"
      add field "UOM"
    }
    
    add layout "AllocationsTab" {
      displayName = "Allocations"
      layout = "DataTab"
      add containerLink "Allocations"
    }
    
    add containerAction "Insert" {
      icon = "system://Plus"
      behavior = Create
    }
    add selectionAction "Delete" {
      icon = "system://Trash"
      behavior = Delete
    }
    add recordAction "Delete" {
      icon = "system://Trash"
      behavior = Delete
      after = Close
    }
    add recordAction "Insert" {
      displayName = "Add Another"
      icon = "system://Plus"
      behavior = Create
    }
    attachments {
    }
  }
  add container "Allocations" {
    visible = False
    fieldsToShow = 3
    listActionsToExpand = 2
    formActionsToExpand = 3
    containerActionsToExpand = 2
    add field "InventoryID" {
      selectorDisplayFormat = KeyDescription
      listPriority = 100
    }
    add field "Location" {
      pickerType = Attached
    }
    add field "LotSerialNbr" {
      pickerType = Attached
    }
    add layout "AllocQtyRow"{
      displayName = "AllocQtyRow"
      layout = "Inline"
      add field "Quantity" {
        selectorDisplayFormat = KeyDescription
        listPriority = 90
      }
      add field "UOM" {
        selectorDisplayFormat = Key
        listPriority = 80
      }
    }
    add field "Description"
    
    add containerAction "Insert" {
      icon = "system://Plus"
      behavior = Create
      redirect = True
    }   
    attachments {
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I was able to figure out what the issue was.
First, Acumatica documentation for the mobile app is not very informative.  So, a great deal has to be just 'Trial and Error'.

For the issue of this problem, what I needed to do was pass the redirect to the "Allocations" container as a "$List" directive, AND, add into the Allocations container both a containerAction and recordAction for "Insert" of a new entry.  (Below is the code)

```
  add container "DocumentDetails" {
    fieldsToShow = 2
    listActionsToExpand = 1
    formActionsToExpand = 2
    containerActionsToExpand = 1
    add group "LineInventoryIdGroup" {
      displayName = "LineInventoryIdGroup"
      collapsed = True
      template = ExpansionPanel
        add field "InventoryID" {
          listPriority = 100
          selectorDisplayFormat = Key
          pickerType = Searchable
        }
        add field "Description" {
          listPriority = 90
        }
    }
    add field "Location"
    add field "LotSerialNbr"
    add layout "LineQuantityRow" {
      displayName = "LineQuantityRow"
      layout = "Inline"
      add field "ShippedQty"
      add field "UOM"
    }
    
    add containerAction "Insert" {
      icon = "system://Plus"
      behavior = Create
    }
    add selectionAction "Delete" {
      icon = "system://Trash"
      behavior = Delete
    }
    add recordAction "Delete" {
      icon = "system://Trash"
      behavior = Delete
      after = Close
    }
    add recordAction "Insert" {
      displayName = "Add Another"
      icon = "system://Plus"
      behavior = Create
    }
    add recordAction "LSSOShipLineBinLotSerial" {
      behavior = Void
      redirect = True
      redirectToContainer = "Allocations$List"
    }
    attachments {
    }
  }
  add container "Allocations" {
    visible = False
    fieldsToShow = 3
    listActionsToExpand = 2
    formActionsToExpand = 3
    containerActionsToExpand = 2
    add field "InventoryID" {
      selectorDisplayFormat = KeyDescription
      listPriority = 100
    }
    add field "Location" {
      pickerType = Attached
    }
    add field "LotSerialNbr" {
      pickerType = Attached
    }
    add layout "AllocQtyRow"{
      displayName = "AllocQtyRow"
      layout = "Inline"
      add field "Quantity" {
        selectorDisplayFormat = KeyDescription
        listPriority = 90
      }
      add field "UOM" {
        selectorDisplayFormat = Key
        listPriority = 80
      }    
    }
    add field "ExpirationDate"
    add field "Description"

    add containerAction "Insert" {
      icon = "system://Plus"
      behavior = Create
    }    
    add recordAction "Insert" {
      displayName = "Add Another"
      icon = "system://Plus"
      behavior = Create
    }    
    attachments {
    }
  }
}
```